# Startup applications in snow leopard

Tags: macos

[Little snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) is an application i installed and does not show up in startup items in system preferences, however the application always starts up whenever the system starts, how does it do this, is there some other place where applications can register themselves so they launch on startup.

EDIT: BELONGS ON SUPERUSER.

Comment: To help out until this gets migrated to superuser: Mac OS X uses `launchd` to handle periodic and recurring tasks. `launchd` jobs are defined using `plist` files. There are some predefined places where `launchd` looks for these, including `~/Library/LaunchAgents`, `/Library/LaunchAgents`, and `/Library/LaunchDaemons`. You might try poking around in those directories for likely looking files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 'Daemon' or a 'Launch Agent' can do that.

Have a look in /Library/LaunchAgent or /Library/LaunchDaemon

There will be quite a few processes that launch without being in the Startup Items section of System Preferences.

Answer (score 3):

Little Snitch runs at a much lower level than normal applications; it is a Kernel extension (kext) which integrates with the Mac OS kernel.

This is why you don't see it appear as a 'normal' registered program in your startup items list, because it's not one of those.

Somebody has put a list of files installed by Little Snitch [here](http://forums.obdev.at/viewtopic.php?t=1558) (link is a couple of years old)